# Merging data with a map in Datamaps package.

Tags: r, merge, datamaps

I'm in the process of making an interactive map for a project I'm working on based on google search engine traffic for the term 'Brexit' over the last 2.5 years. I've made good headway with formatting my data and have been following this online tutorial to help me on my way as I am new with datamaps package:
http://rmaps.github.io/blog/posts/animated-choropleths/

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to merge the data I have in a list with the datamap to correctly produce a coloured choropleth such as that shown in the tutorial. My map appears simply black. My data can be downloaded from here: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xBqApmzAzzYHwDIEuxYiksO5bw5N7EBp

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
#Packages for install.
install.packages("reshape2")
install.packages("Quandl")
install.packages("plyr")
install.packages("rMaps")
install.packages("datamaps")
install.packages("rgdal")
install.packages("kableExtra")
install.packages("funModeling")
install.packages("discretization")
install.packages("sf")
install.packages("maptools")
install.packages("RColorBrewer")

#Packages for run. 
library(reshape2)                 
library(Quandl)
library(plyr)
library(rCharts)
library(rMaps)
library(datamaps)
library(kableExtra)
library(funModeling)
library(discretization)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(maptools)
library(RColorBrewer)

#Find Brexit data set.Obvisouly set your own WD here. 
Brexit.Data <- read.csv("E:/MSc Disso/Transposed Brexit.csv", check.names = FALSE)
#Melt Brexit data set.
datm <- melt(Brexit.Data, 'Year',
             variable.name = 'Country',
             value.name = 'Search Frequency',
             check.names = FALSE

)

#Add breaks to data.                             
datm2 <- transform(datm,
                   fillKey = cut(datm[,3],breaks = c(-Inf,0,9,19,49,Inf),labels = c("0","1-9","10-19","20-49","50+"))
)


#Define CB pallet.
fills = setNames(
  c(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5, 'PuBu'),'white'),
  c(c("0","1-9","10-19","20-49","50+"))
)

#Payload creation for data maps. 
datm3 <- dlply(na.omit(datm2), "Year", function(x){
  y= toJSONArray2 (x, json = F)
  names(y) = lapply(y, '[[', 'Country')
  return(y)
})

datm3

#Data maps.
options(rCharts.cdn = TRUE)
map1 <- Datamaps$new()  
map1$set(
  dom = 'chart_1',
  scope = 'world',
  fills = fills,
  data = datm3[[1]],
  legend = TRUE,
  labels = FALSE
)


map1
```

The problem appears to be that the data is not correctly binding with the map. Any help on this or alternative methods would be massively appreciated.
Thanks, Joe